# What is a Future and how do I use it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-future

I get the following error:

```
A value of type 'Future<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'
```

It might be another type instead of `int`, but basically the pattern is:

```
A value of type 'Future<T>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'
```

So:

- What exactly is a `Future`?
- How do I get the actual value I want to get?
- What widget do I use to display my value when all I have is a `Future<T>`?

Comment: In case you are wondering, this is supposed to be a canonical answer to this topic, since it seems none existed before. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399457/canonical-q-a-for-people-that-have-problems-with-futuret-in-flutter) meta post.

Comment: Feel free to edit both Q and A if you feel something can be improved.

Comment: If you haven't dealt with futures in another programming language, it will take some time to grasp the concepts. I found Google's Flutter in Focus video series invaluable: ☐1.[Isolates and Event Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY); ☐2.[Futures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc); ☐3. [Streams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE); ☐4.[Async/Await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY); ☐5.[Generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF-TBsgIErY)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

<sup>In case you are familiar with [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netcore-3.1) or [`Promise<T>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the `async`/ `await` pattern, then you can skip right to the "How to use a Future with the widgets in Flutter" section.</sup>

## What is a Future and how do I use it?

Well, the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) says:

> An object representing a delayed computation.

That is correct. It's also a little abstract and dry. Normally, a function returns a result. Sequentially. The function is called, runs and returns it's result. Until then, the caller waits. Some functions, especially when they access resources like hardware or network, take a little time to do so. Imagine an avatar picture being loaded from a web server, a user's data being loaded from a database or just the texts of the app in multiple languages being loaded from device memory. That might be slow.

Most applications by default have a single flow of control. When this flow is blocked, for example by waiting for a computation or resource access that takes time, the application just freezes. You may remember this as standard if you are old enough, but in today's world that would be seen as a bug. Even if something takes time, we get a little animation. A spinner, an hourglass, maybe a progress bar. But how can an application run and show an animation and yet still wait for the result? The answer is: asynchronous operations. Operations that still run while your code waits for something. Now how does the compiler know, whether it should actually stop everything and wait for a result or continue with all the background work and wait only in this instance? Well, it cannot figure that out on it's own. We have to *tell* it.

This is achieved through a pattern known as [async](/questions/tagged/async) and [await](/questions/tagged/await). It's not specific to [flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter) or [dart](/questions/tagged/dart), it exists under the same name in many other languages. You can find the documentation for Dart [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Since a method that takes some time cannot return immediately, it will return the promise of delivering a value when it's done.

That is called a `Future`. So the promise to load a number from the database would return a `Future<int>` while the promise to return a list of movies from an internet search might return a `Future<List<Movie>>`. A `Future<T>` is something that *in the future* will give you a `T`.

Lets try a different explanation:

> A future represents the result of an asynchronous operation, and can have two states: uncompleted or completed.

Most likely, as you aren't doing this just for fun, you actually need the results of that `Future<T>` to progress in your application. You need to display the number from the database or the list of movies found. So you want to wait, until the result is there. This is where `await` comes in:

```
Future<List<Movie>> result = loadMoviesFromSearch(input);

// right here, you need the result. So you wait for it:
List<Movie> movies = await result;
```

But wait, haven't we come full circle? Aren't we waiting on the result again? Yes, indeed we are. Programs would be utterly chaotic if they did not have some resemblence of sequential flow. But the point is that using the keyword `await` we have told the compiler, that at this point, while we want to wait for the result, we do not want our application to just freeze. We want all the other running operations like for example animations to continue.

However, you can only use the `await` keyword in functions that themselves are marked as `async` and return a `Future<T>`. Because when you `await` something, then the function that is awaiting can no longer return their result immediately. You can only return what you have, if you have to wait for it, you have to return a promise to deliver it later.

```dart
Future<Pizza> getPizza() async {
    Future<PizzaBox> delivery = orderPizza();        

    var pizzaBox = await delivery;

    var pizza = pizzaBox.unwrap();
    
    return pizza;   
}
```

Our getPizza function has to *wait* for the pizza, so instead of returning `Pizza` immediately, it has to return the promise that a pizza *will be there in the future*. Now you can, in turn, `await` the getPizza function somewhere.

## How to use a Future with the widgets in Flutter?

All the widgets in flutter expect real values. Not some promise of a value to come at a later time. When a button needs a text, it cannot use a promise that text will come later. It needs to display the button *now*, so it needs the text *now*.

But sometimes, all you have is a `Future<T>`. That is where [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) comes in. You can use it when you have a future, to display one thing while you are waiting for it (for example a progress indicator) and another thing when it's done (for example the result).

Let's take a look at our pizza example. You want to order pizza, you want a progress indicator while you wait for it, you want to see the result once it's delivered, and maybe show an error message when there is an error:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/// ordering a pizza takes 5 seconds 
/// and then gives you a pizza salami with extra cheese
Future<String> orderPizza() {
  return Future<String>.delayed(
         const Duration(seconds: 5), 
         () async => 'Pizza Salami, Extra Cheese');
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: PizzaOrder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PizzaOrder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PizzaOrderState createState() => _PizzaOrderState();
}

class _PizzaOrderState extends State<PizzaOrder> {
  Future<String>? delivery;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: delivery != null 
                       ? null 
                       : () => setState(() { 
                            delivery = orderPizza(); 
                         }),
            child: const Text('Order Pizza Now')
          ),
          delivery == null
            ? const Text('No delivery scheduled')
            : FutureBuilder(
              future: delivery,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text('Delivery done: ${snapshot.data}');
                } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Delivery error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              })
        ]);
  }
}
```

This is how you use a `FutureBuilder` to display the result of your future once you have it.

Comment: You might consider adding the equivalent `.then` examples for `async`/`await` and make it clear that `await` is just syntactic sugar for `.then`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore check the comment below this [.then and await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017391/map-is-empty-after-finish-iterate-loop#comment111438805_63017391).

Comment: @dev-aentgs That's inaccurate. `await` is just syntactic sugar for `.then`. It exists to make async code appear more like sync code so that it is easier to understand.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore It is more than syntactic sugar [another reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54515559/13625305)

Comment: @dev-aentgs nested `.then` will have the exact same behavior as `await`. `await` was created to make clear and more understandable code.

Comment: @dev-aentgs And if you really need a reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49540091/13250142) is one from what is IMO a more reliable source.

Comment: I think you are mixing two things: `await` and `.then` are not interchangeable. They do not do the same things. However, a program can achieve the same things with a ton of nested `.then` chains (and at least one `Future.wait`) that it can achieve much cleaner and clearer with async/await. I'm not sure if I would call it syntactic sugar though. Where does it stop? Isn't everything outside of mov/cmp/jmp syntactic sugar?

Comment: They certainly are not *directly* interchangeable, but `Future.wait` would not be necessary if `.then` was implemented correctly. As to whether it's really "syntactic sugar", I guess that can be your own opinion, but it appears to be a consensus the `await` is just syntactic sugar in **many** of the languages that support it.

Comment: @nvoigt Though since you do say "a program can achieve the same things [...] with `.then` [...] that it can achieve much cleaner and clearer with async/await" isn't that what syntactic sugar is?

Comment: Regardless, I think it might be a good idea to provide this information within the answer and show alternatives with `.then`.

Comment: `await` is syntactic sugar for `.then`. `await` is transformed into corresponding `.then` (and possibly `.catchError` and `.whenCompleted`) callbacks.  Anything that can be done with `await` can be done by manually registering appropriate callbacks on the `Future`.  As for where to draw the line: the typical definition of "syntactic sugar" is something that can be removed from the language without removing functionality.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/OTS-ap9_aXc?t=15) is a good starting point for the uninitiated on the "Futures" subject. it is part of a series and the visual work on it helps understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a list of analogies to Dart's `Future` from other languages:

- JS: `Promise`
- Java: `Future`
- Python: `Future`
- C#: `Task`

Just like in other languages Future is a special type of object which allows to use async/await syntax sugar, write asynchronous code in synchronous/linear way. You return Future from an async method rather than accept a callback as a parameter and avoid the callback hell - both Futures and callbacks solve same problems (firing some code at a latter time) but in a different way.

Answer (score 10):

`Future<T>` returning the potential value which will be done by `async` work

Eg:

```
Future<int> getValue() async {
    return Future.value(5);
  }
```

Above code is returning `Future.value(5)` which is of `int` type, but while receiving the value from method we can't use type `Future<int>` i.e

```
Future<int> value = await getValue();  // Not Allowed
// Error
A value of type 'Future<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'
```

To solve above getValue() should be received under `int` type

```
  int value = await getValue(); // right way as it returning the potential value.
```

Comment: I still can't use 
`int value = await getValue();`
inside the widget build method,, 
it says
'The await expression can only be used in an async function.'
because the Build method is not async
Beginner question.. but I don't know where to put it

Comment: yes, you can not use directly, you should use FutureBuilder or create new method and used setState() to updte data

Answer (score 8):

**I hope this key point will be informative, I show it in two different Async methods:**

Note the following method where `showLoading()`, `getAllCarsFromApi()` and `hideLoading()` are inner `Async` methods.

If I put the `await` keyword before `showLoading()`, the **Operation** waits until it's done then goes to the next line but I intentionally removed the `await` because I need my **Loading** dialog be displayed simultaneously with `getAllCarsFromApi()` is being processed, so it means `showLoading()` and `getAllCarsFromApi()` methods are processed on different **Threads**. Finally `hideLoading()` hides the loading dialog.

```
Future<List<Car>> getData() async{
   showLoading();
   final List<Car> cars = await getAllCarsFromApi();
   hideLoading();
   return cars;
}
```

Now look at this another `Async` method, here the `getCarByIdFromApi()` method needs an `id` which is calculated from the `getCarIdFromDatabase()`, so there must be an `await` keyword before the first method to make the **Operation** wait until `id` is calculated and passed to the second method. So here two methods are processed one after another and in a single **Thread**.

```
Future<Car> getCar() async{
   int id = await getCarIdFromDatabase();
   final Car car = await getCarByIdFromApi(id);
   return car;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer is that if a function returns its value with a `delay` of some time, `Future` is used to get its value.

```
Future<int> calculate({required int val1, required int val2}) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    return val1 + val2;
  }
```

if we call the above function as

```
getTotal() async { 

      int result = calculate(val1: 5, val2: 5);

    print(result);
  }
```

we will get the following error:

```
A value of type 'Future<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'
```

[image]

but if we use await before function call it will give the actual returned value from the function after a delay

```
getTotal() async { 

    int result = await calculate(val1: 5, val2: 5);

   print(result);
 }
```

[image]

the keyword `async` is required to use `await` for the Future to get returned value